# How to specify Faust arguments when using app.main()

Tags: python, faust

Currently I run several workers using the command line with the following syntax:

`faust -A <filepath>:app -D <data-log-path> worker -l info -p 6066`

and it works fine. But it seems it would be much nicer to run the `.py` file and have the log-level, data-dir, and port all specified in the:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.main()
```

style. I can't seem to figure out how to add any of the arguments/options listed above to either the defining of the app object (`app = faust.App()`) or the `app.main()` funtion.
I will just add that I'm not sure it's worth doing anyway, as I plan to run all the workers from a shell script. It was just going to be a way to ensure all workers are given a unique port to run on, but i guess i can hard code that into the shell scrip if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common way of achieving this is using `sys.argv`. There's an example of this in the [tabletest.py](https://github.com/robinhood/faust/blob/master/examples/tabletest.py) example:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        sys.argv.extend(['worker', '-l', 'info'])
    app.main()
```

Before continuing, I suggest looking at the worker command line options in [faust.cli.worker](https://fauststream.com/en/latest/reference/faust.cli.worker.html#faust.cli.worker.worker).

Assuming you'd like to hard-code your values in a script, what you'd need to do is:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  import sys
  sys.argv = [__file__, 'worker', '-l', 'info', '-p', '6066', '-f', '<data-log-path>']
  app.main()
```

With this, you can run `yourscript.py` without needing to specify options.